# Hurt my enemies or no?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, revenge-nekama

In the Nusach of the Ari during K'riat Shema Al Hamitah, we pray that no person suffers or gets punished on our account.

In various locations of Tehillim, such as chapter 35 and 109:20, King David asks for Hashem to exact retribution upon his enemies.

**How do we understand what our nature should be towards our enemies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer is from the gemara in [Berachot 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.10a.2), where the wife of Rebbi Meir - Beruria - explains the answer to your question to him, i.e. the resolution to this contradiction is that whenever we pray for retribution upon our enemies, what we mean is, that they should stop sinning, and do teshuva.

> ״וּרְשָׁעִים עוֹד אֵינָם״, כֵּיוָן דְּ״יִתַּמּוּ חַטָּאִים״
> ״וּרְשָׁעִים עוֹד אֵינָם״? אֶלָּא בְּעִי רַחֲמֵי עִלָּוַיְהוּ
> דְּלַהְדְּרוּ בִּתְשׁוּבָה, ״וּרְשָׁעִים עוֹד אֵינָם״.
>
> “And the wicked will be no more.” (Tehillim 104) [If, as you suggest,]
> transgressions shall cease [refers to the demise of the evildoers, how
> is it possible that] the wicked will be no more, [i.e., that they will
> no longer be evil?] Rather, pray for [God to have] mercy on them, that
> they should repent, [as if they repent, then the wicked will be no
> more, as they will have repented.]

(Steinsalz translation and interlinear commentary)